# How to tell when FB.init() completed? How to tell if the user is not connected when to app starts?

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing using facebook plugin with Phonegap/Cordova. I read maybe every single post or example about this plugin in stackoverflow and wherever, but still i have this unresolved issure.

1. When the app starts, i need that If user already logged in --> Continue as logged in to the main page. If user is not logged in --> Present screen with "Push the Connect button to login"

now, when my app starts- i call the "FB.init" method. the problem is, that i don't have any callback to use so i know when it completes, and then check for the login status.

if i subscribe to the auth.statusChange event before the FB.init, then i only get this event raised when the user is already logged in. its not enough, because i also need to know when he is NOT logged in.

if i call "FB.getLoginStatus" just after the FB.init, it doesn't work since this all thing is async and it tries get the login status before the "fb.init()" completed.

in other words, i can't tell when the user is NOT LOGGED IN when the app starts.

thank you, Liran.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i solved the issue right now with timeout + little things.
i really don't like the timeout, but that the only solution i found for the "unknown" session status for the moment. here is my code:

```
// This event will rise when FB.init() completed, ONLY if the user is connected
        var statusChangeRaised = false;
        var statusChangeHandler = function(session) {
            statusChangeRaised = true;
            console.log('auth.statusChange event callback. session: ' + session.status);

            // We only want this handler one time
            FB.Event.unsubscribe('auth.statusChange', statusChangeHandler); 

            handleLoginStatus(d, session, true);
        };
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', statusChangeHandler); 

        // Phonegap native plugin
        FB.init({ appId : _FB_APP_ID,
              nativeInterface : CDV.FB,
              status: true,
              useCachedDialogs : false });

        // The callback can be trusted only if it say the user is NOT connected!
        //  * The scenario that the user is connected is covered by the auth.statusChange event
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(session) {
            console.log("getLoginStatus (just after init) callback. session: " + session.status);

            if (session.status === "notConnected") {
                statusChangeRaised = true;
                handleLoginStatus(d, session, false);
            }
        });

        // The timeout will handle scenario that the user is "unknown", so the auth.StatusChange didn't rise
        //      and also the getLoginStatus cannot be truested,
        setTimeout(function () { 
            if (!statusChangeRaised) {
                FB.Event.unsubscribe('auth.statusChange', statusChangeHandler);

                FB.getLoginStatus(function(session) {
                    console.log('FB.getLoginStatus (inside timeout after FB.init) callback. session: ' + session.status);
                    handleLoginStatus(d, session, true);
                });
            }
        }, 6 * 1000);
```