# FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). in phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to fetch facebook_friendsList in phonegap using the FB.api

I think the problem is the function calling before the app make the fb.init function

here is my code:

```
<script>
      // Initialize the Facebook SDK


      document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
          FB.init({
              appId: '427370550688587',
              nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
              useCachedDialogs: false
          });

          FB.getLoginStatus(handleStatusChange);


          authUser();
          updateAuthElements();


      });

      FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
        if(response.data) {
            var flist;
            $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
                alert(friend.name + ' has id:' + friend.id);
            });
        } else {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });


        //Fetch user's id, name, and picture


  </script>
```

it is alert Error and in the consol this error appear

```
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
```

??

Comment: That's a very common question and possible duplicated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048564/fb-getloginstatus-called-before-calling-fb-init-error-in-console

Comment: I tried this code .. not work for my case

Answer (score 0):

keep track on the post i opened:
[How to tell when FB.init() completed? How to tell if the user is not connected when to app starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193909/how-to-tell-when-fb-init-completed-how-to-tell-if-the-user-is-not-connected-w)

I asked how to tell when fb.init() is completed.. so if someone will anweer mine it will solve your problem as well